# Error while running SSMA script from Command Prompt

Tags: xml, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I wrote an XML script for SSMA and ran it from command prompt once and it worked perfectly. Then I decided to run it again and I have pop-up Windows that says "this app will not work on your computer". And in cmd I have "Access denied". I am the owner of the cmd.exe file and SSMAforMySqlConsole.exe file. And I am using Windows 10.

Maybe reinstall of SSMA will do, but this is meant to work later every hour in script manager so I have no assurance that it will not happen again.

Comment: Try running your command prompt as Adminstrator (right-click > 'Run as Administrator')

Comment: Did it, and it did not work. But I reinstalled SSMA and now i don't have this error running it multiple times.